The difference in behaviour of VS2022 and g++14 compilers
It's the assignment from student work, the task was to write sort using std::nth_element and iterators. I've done this:
template <typename It> void quick_sort(It beg, It end)
{
    if (beg == end || std::distance(beg, end) == 1) return;
    auto dist = std::distance(beg, end) / 2;
    std::nth_element(beg, std::next(beg, dist), end);
}

And it worked only on some inputs. Then I asked a mate about his implementation. And apart that he used one explicit variable to store distance, it was just the same. To be sure I copied his code but nothing changed.
I've read that "Elements are hypothetically sorted with respect to operator<(until C++20)". But for all the people using VS it works and as I'm the only using Linux, so have nobody else to check. To do as much as I can, I tried clang18, but it resulted the same issue. Points for that task now are gone, as I was said at the beginning of the semester to use Windows as all the others, but I just want to know why the things are like this.
Main is:
int main()
{
std::vector<int> v{2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 0};
std::vector<int> v_sorted{0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7};
quick_sort(v.begin(), v.end());
assert(v == v_sorted);

As I see, the border pairs for some input are not sorted.
To add to changing compilers I've also tried to change the second argument for nth_element to random iterator in range argument vector, nothing changed.

std::nth_element doesn't do a full sort, you will need some kind of recursion...

"But for all the people using VS it works". It seems to work, if they use longer vector, it should fail too.

Have you read : nth_element>. The standard requires some partial sorting only (and one standard library implementation might differ from another as long as those requirements are met). Looks like you got "lucky" with gcc and it sorted more than it had to.

@Pepijn Kramer yes, I've read it, but there is a deadlock - I need to know and be accustomed to linux for future work and at my uni literally every professor use Windows and they don't give me any advice the moment that something works on Win and doesn't work for me on linux. So for me the only way to know if I've made a mistake or task was wrong(as it was when I had to point out that there is copy and move elision and it's the cause of move constructor doesn't called, not me written it wrong way) is to ask here or on Reddit...

The copy/move elision is not related to linux/windows but mostly to C++ versions.
For your professors it is important they know about the C++ core guidelines so they can teach current C++ (which should be  mostly OS agnostic). In the end it is mostly a way of working, write code (libraries) and write unit tests and build for various platforms (combinations of compiler versions and OSes).

@Pepijn Kramer it was not OS problem, just the task was to create class with move operators, function returning object of class by value and to demonstrate that when one creates object of the class initialized by the return value of this function move constructor used. But the function returns temporary object and no copy or move produced, so move constructor doesn't do anything because copy or move elision and when I try to use std::move on the result of creation function, static analyzer complains. But this argument didn't play, so some points for the assignment moved away.

That sucks, and shows the teacher doesn't understand the rules of C++17. Show him this link : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision. And point out "guaranteed copy elision". The return object is kind of "allocated" by the callee (even if it shows up as a local variable in a function) and it is never moved or copied to.. Note the behavior prior to C++17 could be as teacher still thinks it works
